# Add compulsory commit message format in GIT

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I want to do configuration in GIT that will enforce all commit messages to follow certain pattern.
How can I do that?

EDIT: I want it for Github.

Comment: Shor answer:  Overwrite (or create) one of the scripts in .git/hooks and make it executable.


Check this out for more info:

https://githooks.com/

Comment: @lucascavalcante This will enforce only me for all my branches to have proper commit messages. I want to set up something globally that restricts everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to set up a CI job that checks the commit messages and verifies they're in the format you want.  In some environments, it's also possible to use a `pre-receive` hook, although that's not possible on github.com (but it is on GitHub Enterprise Server).

That command will look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

git rev-list $1 | \
  xargs -L1 sh -c 'git log --format=%B -1 $0 | grep -qs Signed-off-by'
```

In my case, I'm passing the command a range of commits on the branch (that is, in the form `BASE..HEAD`) and my check is verifying that each commit contains the text `Signed-off-by`.  You can replace the `grep` command with whatever you like, provided it exits 0 if the commit message is acceptable and nonzero if it is not.  Then, the script itself will exit 0 on success, and nonzero if the commits are unacceptable, and you can then reject the commits.

You may wish to help developers by offering them a `commit-msg` hook as well using a similar technique.  However, as [outlined in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#restrict-with-hooks), mandatory client-side hooks are both ineffective, since they can trivially be bypassed with the developer without anyone noticing, and also annoying to some advanced developers, so you should make them opt-in for those who want them.